# Kinect and EMGU (OpenCV) - BitmapSource issue

Tags: c#, opencv, kinect, emgucv, bitmapsource

Alright, so basically I am trying to use openCV with the Kinect (Microsoft's new Kinect 1.0 SDK).  I am very new to both C# and Kinect.  But what I want to do is use the kinect for facial recognition using EMGU (openCV wrapper for C#).  So far I have successfully captured the video stream from the kinect, converted it into an EMGU Image<>, then converted it a Byte[] array so that I can use the BitmapSource to display my image on the screen.

While that works fine, problems seem to arise when I try to actually do some image processing with the Image<> class.  It actually seems to be processing fine, but it is not very fast.  This wouldn't necessarily be a problem for me, but now the BitmapSource isn't being displayed at all.

Here is an example of my code to detect faces:

```
img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(clone);
haar = new HaarCascade("directory");

Image<Gray, Byte> gray;
using (HaarCascade face = new HaarCascade("blablabla.xml"))
using (HaarCascade eye = new HaarCascade("blarg.xml"))
{

using ( gray = img.Convert<Gray, Byte>()) //Convert it to Grayscale
{
  MCvAvgComp[] facesDetected = face.Detect(gray, 1.1, 1,  mgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new System.Drawing.Size(img.Width / 8, img.Height / 8));
  foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected)
  {
    img.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.Blue), 2);
    imgDoneProc = img.ToBitmap();
  }
 }
}
```

Then I use the BitmapSource.Create() :

```
BitmapSource bmapa = BitmapSource.Create(PImage.Width, PImage.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, bmpBytes, PImage.Width * PImage.BytesPerPixel);

image1.Source = bmapa;
```

(PImage is the stream from the Kinect; bmpBytes is a Byte[] converted from the Image<>)

So, if I comment out the code that does the image processing, all of the converting back and forth works fine.  When I add the image proc code, I can write to the console some useful data, but the image is not displayed.  I have also noticed that the 'bmapa' is not updated quickly.  That is the only noticeable difference other than nothing being displayed in image1.

So, am I using BitmapSource incorrectly, or is there are way speed up my code or perhaps slow BitmapSource's "refresh rate"?  Because when I am just converting between data structures, I get a steady stream from the kinect and all works fine.

Thanks,
Brent